# How do I set an image as a video overlay with GPUImage without the image being resized?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I'm using a `GPUImagePicture` and the output from a `GPUImageVideoCamera` to add an image overlay to video using the `GPUImageAddBlendFilter` like this:

```
GPUImagePicture *myPicture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
[myPicture processImage];

[myPicture addTarget:blendFilter];
[myVideoCamera addTarget:blendFilter];

[blendFilter addTarget:myPreviewView];
```

I want myImage to be centered in the frame, but it is being resized to fit to the video camera's frame, leading to some stretching distortions.  How can I add an overlay that's smaller than the video frame size without the overlay being resized?

I understand that the `blendFilter` needs two textures of equal size, so how can I work around this?

Comment: Things are a little limited right now in terms of handling inputs of different sizes, but other people have used transforms for this on the image to shrink it so that it's the right relative size in the video overlay.

Comment: Thanks Brad.  I've played around with the transform filter a bit, but I think I've found that the image is resized to fit the video frame before a transform filter can scale it again.  This leads to a distorted image, as it is essentially blown up then shrunken down to original size.

Comment: My current workaround is using drawInRect to draw the image in a context of size matching the video output size, then rendering the context to a UIImage and using that as the source picture -- effectively adding a transparent border around the original image.  The only thing lacking with this is that updating the source picture's position frame-by-frame is a very expensive operation, since the GPUImagePicture needs to be re-initialized with a new image every time the image's position changes.

Comment: I mean using a transform before the blend. If you shrink the image to counteract the stretch before the blend, using a transparent background color on the transform, you should be able to get the result you want. You just have to figure out how far to overshoot in which axis to offset the stretch when the image is matched to the video aspect ratio.